# Why does OS X 10.8.3 Mountain Lion performance lag when display is turned to scaled?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

I'm running OS X 10.8.3 on an MBP and have the display resolution set to 1920 x 1200. But at that resolution, everything feels really laggy?. Why does OS X 10.8.3 Mountain Lion performance lag when display is turned to scaled?

Comment: Retina Macbook Pro? Internal display?

Comment: Yes. Retina Macbook Pro. Internal display.